# PHP: Is there a simple way to parse a list of numbers (as a string, like "1-3,5,7-9") into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, list, methods, numbers

I tried searching for this both here and on Google, so if I missed something obvious, I apologize.  It's possible I simply don't know the name for the formatting of these numbers.

What I'm looking to do is to start with a string, like "1-3,5,7-9" and have it turn into a PHP array with the following entries: 1,2,3,5,7,8,9

I know how to do this by using preg_split on a comma, then iterating through and expanding any - marks, but I feel like there must be an easier/better way.

**EDIT**

I didn't make this clear, but the string needs to include SPANS!  That means if my string was "1-9" my resulting array should be "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" NOT JUST "1,9".  Sorry for that not being clear before.

Comment: you looked at explode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I'm glad everyone here read the question closely...

Comment: I edited the post... my issue is with spans, like "1-5" needs to result in "1,2,3,4,5" not just "1,5"

Comment: I thought it was clear, but apparently @animunson was the only other person that noticed :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean by "expanding". Anyway, here's how I would do it with [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) and [`range`](http://php.net/range):

```
$input = '1-3,5,7-9';
$output = array();

foreach (explode(',', $input) as $nums) {
    if (strpos($nums, '-') !== false) {
        list($from, $to) = explode('-', $nums);
        $output = array_merge($output, range($from, $to));
    } else {
        $output[] = $nums;
    }
}
```

If there's a better way that doesn't use `eval` (or PCRE `e` modifier), I don't know any.

Here is, *for your amusement*, a one-liner (that unfortunately uses `eval`) that returns the same result, but...

**Disclaimer**: Using `eval` is not recommended in most cases because it can create security risks and other issues. **I wouldn't use it** but it's still feasible.

With that said, here it is:

```
$output = explode(',', preg_replace('/([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/e', 'implode(",", range($1, $2));', $input));
```

Answer (score 5):

The routine above works well but has a number of shortcomings:

1. Spaces in the string upset the routine
2. Duplicates are not removed e.g. 5,4-7 gives 5,4,5,6,7
3. The numbers are not sorted.

I have changed the code to sort out these issues:

```
function parsenumbers($input)
{
    /*
     * This routine parses a string containing sets of numbers such as:
     * 3
     * 1,3,5
     * 2-4
     * 1-5,7,15-17
     * spaces are ignored
     * 
     * routine returns a sorted array containing all the numbers
     * duplicates are removed - e.g. '5,4-7' returns 4,5,6,7
     */
    $input = str_replace(' ', '', $input); // strip out spaces
    $output = array();
    foreach (explode(',', $input) as $nums)
    {
        if (strpos($nums, '-') !== false)
        {
            list($from, $to) = explode('-', $nums);
            $output = array_merge($output, range($from, $to));
        }
        else
        {
            $output[] = $nums;
        }
    }

    $output = array_unique($output, SORT_NUMERIC); // remove duplicates
    sort($output);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Good function, thank you. If I can add my cent.
`$output[] = $nums;` returns a string, I changed it like this
`$output[] = $nums + 0;` to get all integers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a simple built in way, as it's not something that's all the common I doubt there's something built in.

The way you're describing sounds like a reasonable approach.  It's possible to do it with just a single iteration through the string, but unless it's a known performance issue I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: +1 I definitely overlooked the spans and viewed them as delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '1-3,5,7-9';
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $a){
  $x = explode('-', $a);
  if(count($x) === 2){
    $x = range($x[0], $x[1]);
  }
  $result = array_merge($result, $x);
}
print_r($result);
```

Not sure how efficient this is, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Went away to do this and I come back to see 2 answers already. :(

```
<?php
function arrex($s){
    $arr = explode("-", $s);
    $v=$arr[0] + 1;
    $val = array();
            while($v!=$arr[1]){
                 $val[$v] = $v;
                   $v++;
            }
    array_unshift($val, $arr[0]);
    array_push($val, $arr[1]);
return $val;
}
$s = "1-9";
print_r(arrex($s));
?>
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
)
```